# TypeError: .findAll is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm learning and making a small project with `sequelize` and i'm stuck in this step. I can't make a simple get request for find all my object on the database.

I always have an error like `TypeError: Transport.findAll is not a function`

---

- models/index.js

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(file => {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
    })
    .forEach(file => {
        const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

- models/transport.js

```js
'use strict';

const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Transport extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            Transport.hasMany(models.Conditionnement,{
                foreignKey: 'transportId',
                as: 'conditionnements'
            });
            Transport.belongsTo(models.Transporteur,{
                foreignKey: 'transporteurId',
                onDelete: 'CASCADE'
            });
        }
    };
    Transport.init({
        date: DataTypes.DATE,
        destination: DataTypes.STRING,
        isCharged: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'Transport',
    });
    return Transport;
};
```

- controllers/transport.js

```js
const Transport = require('../models/transport');
const fs = require('fs');
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

exports.getAllTransports = (req, res, next) => {
        Transport.findAll({})
    .then(transports => res.status(200).jsons(transports))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try returning the initialization:

```
return Transport.init({...});
```

Comment: Thank's. I have de same result

Answer (score 0):

Finally find the solution. I had into controllers/transport.js the followings :

```
const db = require('../models/index');
```

and :

```
db.Transport.findAll()
```